# Residue field of a finite extension under certain conditions

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $E/F$ be a finitely generated field extension of transcendence degree one. Suppose that $F$ is algebraically closed in $E$ and $t\in E$ is a transcendental element over $F$. Let $B$ be the integral closure of $A:=F[t]$ in $E$. If $m$ is a maximal ideal of $B$ lying over $(t)$, is it true that $B/m=F$?

Answer (score 0):

OK, sorry. This is trivial. One may take $E:=\mathbb Q(t,\sqrt{t+2})=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{t+2})$. But is it true if we further assume that $E$ is not purely transcendental over $F$?